# Access oracle database by databricks

Tags: oracle, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to access oracle db by my databricks, I have installed latest oracle jdbc in my cluster. Below is the code

```
df= = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
      option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@HostName(129.80.**.***:<ProtNumber(1521)>/<ServieName>")
     option("dbtable", "schema.tableName")
     option("user", "userName")
     option("password", "password")
     option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
)
```

When I execute this code I am getting  error `SparkSecurityException: {INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS] Insufficient privileges`

When I use the same details to login into Oracle SQL Developer, I am able to login and access the data.
Can someone please tell me what is the issue here.

I was expecting to create a dataframe by loading Oracle table into it.

Comment: Has the IP for the clusters you’re trying to use been whitelisted on the Oracle database?

Comment: When I access the Oracle Db using SQL Developer, It didn't ask for whitelisting for my laptop.

Comment: Maybe the IPs you’re using on your local machine are already whitelisted. Are you using a vpn?

Comment: No, It's not whitelisted. . I am sure. Also, I tried to execute the code with and without the VPN, Both time I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, The error is coming because the user in databricks does not have permission to connect to external data source. Admin of Databricks cluster needs to execute below code to provide you the access:

%sql
GRANT SELECT ON ANY FILE TO `username`